# Null-homotopic map from $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

I need to prove that a smooth map $f\colon SL_2(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow S^4$
is homotopic to the constant map. 
I think that computing the corresponding homotopy groups may help, but I don't see how to do this.

Comment: Does it help to know that $\pi_1(SL_2(\mathbb{R}))=\mathbb{Z}$ and $\pi_1(S^4)=\{1\}$?

Comment: $SL(2,R)$ is 3-dimensional; do you know how to show that every smooth map $f: SL(2,R)\to S^4$ is not surjective?

Answer (score 1):

$SL(2,R)$ is a deformation retract of its maximal compact subgroup which is $S^1$. So it is equivalent to show that every map $S^1\rightarrow S^4$ is homotopic to the constant map, a fact which is equivalent to the fact that $\pi_1(S^4)=1$.